# How do I measure the width available for text in a tree view item?

Tags: windows, winapi

I have a standard Win32 tree view control.  I'm putting a file name into the root node. To avoid asking the user to use a horizontal scroll bar I would like to shorten the text using `PathCompactPath` to fit in the space available on the control.

[image]

So, in order to do this I need to measure the distance marked in the screenshot above.  I know about [`TVM_GETITEMRECT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773610.aspx) but it returns a rect that includes the space taken up by the icon.

So, how can I obtain the metric I need? Is it even possible to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you specifying `TRUE` or `FALSE` for the `wParam` parameter of `TVM_GETITEMRECT`?  It should be `TRUE` to get the node's text rectangle.  Once you have that, you can subtract the rectangles's left pixel value from the client width of the TreeView to get the width you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks Remy. That will do it. I was passing TRUE but then using Right-Left. Which of course depends on the contents of the item. I simply had not thought about the fact that the returned rect gives me location as well as size.