# How can I make a tree view re-think whether or not a horizontal scroll bar is needed?

Tags: delphi

Consider the following very simple unit:

**Unit1.pas**

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Classes, Controls, Forms, ComCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    TreeView1: TTreeView;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

const
  SLongString = 'blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah';

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Node: TTreeNode;
begin
  TreeView1.Width := 200;
  Node := TreeView1.Items.Add(nil, SLongString);
  Node.Text := 'blah';
end;

end.
```

**Unit1.dfm**

```
object Form1: TForm1
  ClientHeight = 137
  ClientWidth = 216
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object TreeView1: TTreeView
    Left = 8
    Top = 8
    Width = 198
    Height = 121
  end
end
```

Add this to a VCL Forms app and run. The result looks like this:

[image]

I would like for the horizontal scroll bar not to be showing.  How can I achieve this?

Now I realise that I could remove the line of code that assigns the very long string. But this is a cut-down program for the purpose of my question. In [the real app the text of the nodes is changing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693995/how-do-i-measure-the-width-available-for-text-in-a-tree-view-item) and I want the scroll bars to show if they are needed, and not show if they are not needed.

I know about the [`TVS_NOHSCROLL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760013.aspx) style but I can't use that. Sometimes the tree view contains text that is wider than the available space. And sometimes not.

I also want to use `TTreeView` and do not want to use virtual tree view. Not that I have anything against virtual tree view, just that my app is currently using `TTreeView`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Very simple, use `TreeView1.Items.BeginUpdate/EndUpdate` methods and the scrollbar will be calculated accordingly.

like this:

```
...
 TreeView1.Items.BeginUpdate;
 // change your nodes here
 TreeView1.Items.EndUpdate
```

Comment: Thanks. Just the job. It's the `WM_SETREDRAW(1, 0)` in `EndUpdate` that does the work. Not quite sure why it has the effect.

Comment: Relavent Raymond Chen: [There's a default implementation for WM_SETREDRAW, but you might be able to do better](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/01/24/10119211.aspx)