# Item only show partial text in List View

Tags: listview, delphi

I am using Delphi XE3. In a form, I add a TListView and set its ViewStyle to vsList. Then I try to add an item with a long text to the list view, as follows:

```
    procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
      ListItem: TListItem;
    begin
      ListItem := ListView1.Items.Add;
      ListItem.Caption := 'A very very long text long text long text long text long text';
    end;
```

However, the added item will only show partial text, as below:

[image]

How to solve the problem?

Comment: @TomBrunberg Don't think so, perfectly possible for the full text to be display in list view style

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes, this is a perfect legal question?

Comment: Right @DavidHeffernan as the answer shows. I was uncertain, hence the *I think?* in my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BeginUpdate/EndUpdate` recalculates columns widths (but why this is not done during adding?) and calls `WM_SETREDRAW` (perhaps adding redraws only rectangle with "old" item size)

```
var
  ListItem: TListItem;
begin
  ListView1.Items.BeginUpdate;
  try
    ListItem := ListView1.Items.Add;
    ListItem.Caption := 'A very very long text long text long text long text long text';
  finally
    ListView1.Items.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: any chance of an explanation?

Comment: I see what updating does perform, but good explanation has to point what was missed in simple adding item...

Comment: [This reminds me of a similar question from @DavidHeffernan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12696870/800214)

Comment: - *..  recalculates columns widths .. "* - Only those that exist. I mean you don't have to have any columns in vsList mode. What matters is the `WM_SETREDRAW` calls, seems to trigger some sort of internal layout calculation.

Comment: I think the using of BeginUpdate/EndUpdate will improve the performance when updating a large volume of items. That is the reason why Delphi does not update when each item is changed.

Answer (score 0):

ListView_SetIconSpacing changes the size of the icon / item:

```
uses commctrl;
```

[...]

```
ListView_SetIconSpacing(ListView1.Handle, ListView1.Width, 25);
```